# How do handle the send email for REST api?

Tags: web-services, email, rest

I want to build an service that for user account sign up.
The request send a POST request with JSON to */users/* and the result will be a message indicate action failure or success with an email vi SMTP to user input email.

As I test my function, I see that the response take a (quite) long time for sending the email.
I decided to send the email by an other thread and return 202 status code so the response will return to user quickly.
My question:

1. I'm doing it right?
2. If not, what is the better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way. `HTTP 202 Accepted` is the correct code to implify a started asynchronic process which does not require the HTTP User-Agent to wait for completion.

Only problem I see is invalid email addresses from user input. You should at least check the syntax validity against Email address specification ([RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#page-16)) or [other methods](http://girders.org/blog/2013/01/31/dont-rfc-validate-email-addresses/). One step up would be validate the email address existence from SMTP server and  maybe respond with `HTTP 400 Bad Request` in case of email address not found.